# anyway to copy filename to clipboard history in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I am in a directory called temp. I have two files `abcd.png` and `xyz.png`. I want to delete `xyz.png` and rename `abcd.png` to `xyz.pn`g. I was thinking that there will be a bash command to copy the name of the file `xyz.png` and the delete the `xyz.png` using rm and the change the name of abcd.png to `xyz.png` from the command history.

AnyIdea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Bash history:

```
rm  xyz.png
mv abcd.png !$
```

Make sure that `rm` is the last command you ran before running `mv`. See more information [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) about using the history in Bash.

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

`rm  xyz.png`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

`mv abcd.png`<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

and Bash will insert the last argument of the last command into the command line so that it will look like this

`mv abcd.png xyz.png`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have manually made the changes but it is very useful to know!